# Не выполняются тесты

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты

Создал библиотеку классов и unittest приложение. При запуске тестов в unittest ничего не происходит и говорится что выполнено 0 тестов, хотя они есть.

```
public class PasswordValidator
{
    public int ValidatePassword(string password)
    {
        int score = 0;

        if (ContainsDigits(password)) score++;
        if (ContainsLowercaseLetters(password)) score++;
        if (ContainsUppercaseLetters(password)) score++;
        if (ContainsSpecialCharacters(password)) score++;
        if (IsLongEnough(password)) score++;

        return score;
    }

    private bool ContainsDigits(string password)
    {
        return password.Any(char.IsDigit);
    }

    private bool ContainsLowercaseLetters(string password)
    {
        return password.Any(char.IsLower);
    }

    private bool ContainsUppercaseLetters(string password)
    {
        return password.Any(char.IsUpper);
    }

    private bool ContainsSpecialCharacters(string password)
    {
        return Regex.IsMatch(password, @"[!@#$%^&*()_+{}\[\]:;<>,.?~\\-]");
    }

    private bool IsLongEnough(string password)
    {
        return password.Length > 7;
    }
}
```

А вот код unit test

```
[TestClass]
public class PasswordValidatorTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test_Password_With_No_Criteria()
    {
        PasswordValidator validator = new PasswordValidator();
        int score = validator.ValidatePassword("password");
        Assert.AreEqual(0, score);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Test_Password_With_Digits()
    {
        PasswordValidator validator = new PasswordValidator();
        int score = validator.ValidatePassword("Passw0rd");
        Assert.AreEqual(1, score);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Test_Password_With_Lowercase_Letters()
    {
        PasswordValidator validator = new PasswordValidator();
        int score = validator.ValidatePassword("PASSWORD");
        Assert.AreEqual(1, score);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Test_Password_With_Uppercase_Letters()
    {
        PasswordValidator validator = new PasswordValidator();
        int score = validator.ValidatePassword("password");
        Assert.AreEqual(1, score);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Test_Password_With_Special_Characters()
    {
        PasswordValidator validator = new PasswordValidator();
        int score = validator.ValidatePassword("P@ssw0rd");
        Assert.AreEqual(1, score);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Test_Password_With_Length()
    {
        PasswordValidator validator = new PasswordValidator();
        int score = validator.ValidatePassword("P@ss1");
        Assert.AreEqual(1, score);
    }
}
```

Вот что выходит при попытке выполнения теста[image: описание]

Comment: глупый вопрос, но всё же спрошу, вы нажимали на зелёный треугольничек? Если да, билдится ли ваш проект без ошибок (посмотрите в консоле)?

Comment: нажимал. Он просто не видит тесты и говорит: найдено тестов 0

Comment: пробовали перезапустить студию?

Comment: да пробовал. Решил сделать заново сборку и выходит, что в PasswordValidatorTests.dll нет доступных тестов

Comment: всё. Я исправил проблему. Надо было обновить MSTest